# How to integrate gem using Webpacker instead of the asset pipeline? [Rails 6]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, asset-pipeline, webpacker

I want to use the [local_time](https://github.com/basecamp/local_time) gem, but as per its installation instructions it should be included in the asset pipeline:

> **Installation**
>
> 1. Add gem 'local_time' to your Gemfile.
> 2. Include local-time.js in your application's JavaScript bundle.
>
> Using the asset pipeline:
>
> `//= require local-time`

However, I'm using Webpacker and I can't figure out how to integrate the gem with it. Where should I include the line above? Or is it another strategy entirely?

Answer (score 2):

1 Solution: install the rails-erb-loader, useful for embedding Ruby files in Javascript.

$ rails webpacker:install:erb

//  packs/application.js   //

Then if you have a gem that provides style sheets, you can import them as follows

import "<%= File.join(Gem.loaded_specs['yourgem'].full_gem_path, 'app', 'assets', 'stylesheets', 'yourfile.css') %>";

For Ruby gems with Javascript, how to import them can vary, but for many, it will be as simple as importing the files from the gem.

import "<%= File.join(Gem.loaded_specs['yourgem'].full_gem_path, 'app', 'assets', 'javascripts', 'yourfile') %>";

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it working. I took a hint from the instructions for the `local-time npm package` mentioned in the link and added this to `app\javascript\packs\application.js`, before the other `requires`:

```
require("local-time").start()
```